# Nginx rewrite rule only for the first request

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a requirement where there needs to be a nginx rewrite rule such that when I launch the URL - http://localhost:8554/web-app, the path should be changed to http://localhost:8554/web-app/login.jsp

However this redirect should happen only when I type http://localhost:8554/web-app/ or http://localhost:8554/web-app and not for the subsequent requests post login. The url contains /web-app uri after login so no redirect should happen after user logs-in.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should do this from your web app rather than from nginx.

Comment: Thanks much for the response, appreciate your help. I'll have to figure out how to do this in embedded tomcat as that is what our application is using. Any pointers on how to do this in tomcat is appreciated, however Thank you for the info/hint.